# Windows Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I am using Windows 7. I know that to Shutdown/ Restart windows in Remote desktop connection the key combination are : Ctrl+Alt+End. While restarting with that command from remote connection it is restarting but it disconnects the remote desktop. So is there any option to restart without disconnecting the remote desktop connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sir , its pretty tough to restart the machine without disconnecting from RDP . RDP service dies when machine reboot hence it wont catch up connection back . You can use TeamViewer , LogMein RIM tools which let you establish connection automatically on reboot .You can try optimizing the RDP connection settings to reconnect on connection drop . Try and update . All the best .

http://www.informationweek.com/byte/personal-tech/desktop-operating-systems/how-to-optimize-remote-desktop-in-window/231600221

Comment: Who the hell downvoted my question? You people are not at all letting me grow up points!!

Comment: Chill Buddy , Happens.  Try to adhere to stackoverflow rules dear

Answer (score 0):

If you restart the PC, you are going to lose the network connection to that PC, therefor the connection WILL drop.

The onlt way around this is to get something that does not display through Windows, (So no software solutions).

IP KVMs such as [this Lantronix](http://www.provantage.com/lantronix-slslp400ps2-01~7LAN9049.htm?source=googleps) are your best bet. As these give you BIOS level access (You can access the BIOS remotely), and run their own operating system (The Lantronix Spider which I have used) runs a micro Linux kernel.